# onChange not working to show/hide a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange, selectionchanged

I have a piece of code with HTML & JavaScript.

HTML code is

```
<select name="paytype" id="paytype" onchange="insProviderTable()">
            <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
            <option value="Credit" selected>Credit</option>
        </select>

<div id="insuranceDetails" style="display:none">
    BULB
</div>
```

and JavaScript code is

```
function insProviderTable() {   
        if ($('#paytype').val() == 'Credit') {
            $('#insuranceDetails').show(1000);
        }
        else {
            $('#insuranceDetails').hide(1000);
        }
    };

$(insProviderTable);
```

The issue is on page load the div `insuranceDetails` is appearing but if I change the value of `paytype` to Cash, nothing happens.

Please let me know where I am mistaken.

jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/5bjfxdq4/

Comment: update your fiddle, not all your code is there

Comment: I have updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5bjfxdq4/4/ ...Now tell where is the problem..?

Comment: I dont see where the problem is!

Comment: @DhavalMarthak, @Rakesh_Kumar you both have removed the `onLoad` `function $(insProviderTable);` I want that also to run this function on page load.

Comment: Are you using jqueryUI library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the inline onchange-handler and write:

```
function insProviderTable() {
    if ($('#paytype').val() == 'Credit') {
        $('#insuranceDetails').show(1000);
    } else {
        $('#insuranceDetails').hide(1000);
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#paytype').on('change', function () {
        insProviderTable();
    });

    insProviderTable();      
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/way4paLe/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

You can trigger `change()` on load like following:

```
$("#paytype").on("change",function(){
      if ($(this).val() == 'Credit') {
            $('#insuranceDetails').show(1000);
        }
        else {
            $('#insuranceDetails').hide(1000);
        }
}).change();
```

### [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/5bjfxdq4/11/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to the bottom of your existing script

```
$("#paytype").bind('change', function(){
$(insProviderTable);
```

});

Add between main body and

```
$(insProviderTable);
```

Hope this helps, let me know how you get on!

Comment: What is the point to write `$(insProviderTable);` instead of `insProviderTable();` inside event handler? And also: _It's not an issue: there is outdated inline JS `onchange=""` in original code. Moreover, `$("#paytype").bind` might not work, if script is in `<head>`_.